# Enviar csfr_token de um cliente

Tags: laravel, restful, token

Gostaria de saber se tem como enviar um csrf_token de uma aplicação cliente para o meu webservice laravel

Ou será que tenho que desativar verificação de TOKEN do laravel?

Se tem como enviar, como é?

Que eu quero testar do Postman e posteriormente de uma aplicação

Quero fazer solicitação via post

Obrigado!

Comment: Web Api????????

Comment: Você sabe? Ajuda ai

Comment: Eu perguntei é uma WebApi em Laravel?

Comment: Sim. Estou é para receber no laravel. É que eu não tinha entendido, desculpa

Comment: Se tem que liberar o cors https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors (https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors) com esse pacote e depois trabalhar as requisições com token com outro pacote https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth que é o de autenticação.

Comment: Ai com ele uma aplicacao cliente podera enviar token?

Comment: Um libera o recebimento de verb, e o outro trabalha a parte do token de autorização, como a sua pergunta é ampla é complicado responder tudo numa só. e sua pergunta na verdade está errada, o conceito.

Comment: Então parece que é meio complicado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75634/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-adventistaam).